# 3 approximation algorithm(randomised or deterministic)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, approximation, deterministic

Let 3 colorful sets problem. Given M sets of size three over {1...n} elements. We are given in other words sets S1, S2, ... , Sm where, for every i, Si = {x, y, z} for some x, y, z ∈ {1, ... , n}. What I want to find is to pick a set of elements E ⊆ {1, ... , n} so that to maximize the number of sets that contain exactly one element in E, namely, to maximize the |{i |Si ∩ E| = 1}| . A solution could use a 3 approximation polynomial time algo.

I am thinking a randomized algo that guarantee the approximation ration or a deterministic one. I have some ideas but I am not sure how to actually implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a "3 approximation"? An approximation taking O(n³) effort? What have you tried and what specific problem(s) did you encounter? Can you show your current code?

Comment: Hint: include each element in E independently with probability 1/3.